# PHP Validation Button

Tags: php, html, ajax

I would like to have on my HTML page a simple button allowing me if right clicked one, click activate every time my PHP script.
I tried with this code, without any positive result for the moment:

```
//My html code
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-16" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css.css">
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <button onclick="doTheFunction();">Run the script</button>
            <script>
            function doTheFunction(){
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.open("POST","script.php",true);
            xmlhttp.send();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
              };
            }
            }
            </script>

    </main>
    <footer>
        <?php echo $footer; ?>
    </footer>
</body>
```

A part of my php code :

```
echo "$result";
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you expect? Also you're not doing anything with your ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is doing nothing with the result of Ajax. I suggest starting [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_create.asp) as a reference. The most important thing you're missing is:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
```

Where "demo" is the Id of the element you want to load the Ajax result into. Otherwise nothing will happen with that result.

**EDIT**

Let's clean up your code so scripts and html are separate:

```js
function doTheFunction(){
     xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
     //Set this before sending!!
     xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
         }
     };
     }
    //No reason to post
    xmlhttp.open("GET","theme/generator/gensent.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<head>
    <title><?php echo $pageTitle; ?></title>
    <meta charset="UTF-16" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css.css">
<style></style>
</head>
<body>
    <main id="demo">
        <button onclick="doTheFunction();">Run the script</button>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <?php echo $footer; ?>
    </footer>
</body>
```

I would put the `<script>` tag at the end of your html, after closing the body, or include it in the header from another file. Note- I use GET since no sensitive info is transferred, the script should load after the HTML- hence put at the end, and finally you need a tag with the Id for this to actually work.

Comment: Thank you for answering and thank you for your advice. However, I have added your code to mine but unfortunately nothing happens.

Comment: Post your html, and we'll see how to fix it. You need a 'div' or some other element  with `id=demo` as I have written it. I usually use a special id, like "ajax".

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification !